# how do I know which partition I'm running?

Tags: linux

I would like to find the partition I'm running my linux, like SDA1 or SDB2, etc, How do I get this?

Comment: Could you provide the output of `fdisk -l` ?

Comment: if you just wish see which partition you are on:  cd /var/www/html  && df -h .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands `mount` and `df` will display all partitions currently in use and their mount points. If you are only using a single partition under linux, look for the one mounted on /.